как в оператор while передать значение переменной
Мне надо чтобы while True прерывался при нажатии на определенную клавишу клавиатуры. Как передать событие нажатия в тело этого оператора?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Воспользоваться библиотекой keyboard как вариант‍♀️


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1588402/562052 2) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1588402/562052 3) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1590122/562052


Я начинающий. Пишу свою первую прогу-игру змейка. Суть проблемы в том, что змейка "движется" пока я держу клавишу-стрелку нажатой. Хотел чтобы она двигалась сама с помощью While, но не могу в этот цикл "вставить" событие нажатия на другую стрелку.

@user23279256 дополните свой вопрос кодом, который уже написали, так будет проще вам подсказать‍♀️

import keyboard

while True:
 if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):  # если клавиша "q" нажата...
  print("Цикл прерван!")
  break
 else: 
  # Ваш код скрипта здесь


Спасибо Вам огромное! Подскажите, пожалуйста, а можно  ли в тело while передать значение какой-либо переменной извне?

is_pressed неблокирующая функция, ЦП от такого кикла улетит в небеса.. Тут хотя бы тайм.слип(0.01) поставить‍♀️

Может быть. Я позже проверю кто там куда улетает, сейчас комп занят шибко. Я бы вообще в такой  ситуации не пользовался while True. Но таково условие. С другой стороны, я сам, например, использую такой цикл в комбинации с input(). Если пользователь введёт неправильные данные, ему предлагается ввести их вновь. В этом случае никто никуда не улетает.

Я начинающий. Пишу свою первую прогу-игру змейка. Суть проблемы в том, что змейка "движется" пока я держу клавишу-стрелку нажатой. Хотел чтобы она двигалась сама с помощью While, но не могу в этот цикл "вставить" событие нажатия на другую стрелку.

Я не претендую на самое правильное решение. Это то, которое мне пришло на ум.

@FoxFox input является блокирующей функцией, пока не нажмёшь enter цикл повторно не крутанёт. В то время как is_pressed просто проверит список нажатых клавишь и цикл полетит дальше..

Я написал о том, как я использую while True. Ну прочтите  наконец внимательно! Использование input в моём случае не приводит к перегрузке процессора. А вообще, в любом, самом несчастном учебнике, сказано: остерегайтесь использовать такое, оно может оказаться проблемным. Я знаю как использовать бесконечные циклы и не создаю себе проблем.

@FoxFox если вы знаете, но при этом публикуете ответ создающий проблемы, то я вас не очень понимаю ‍♀️

В чём проблема? Это готовая программа? Это идея. Вот это кто написал: Воспользоваться библиотекой keyboard как вариант‍♀️ – Amgarak Commented1 час назад ? Это тоже самое, что и я написал.

@FoxFox отнюдь. Я дал комментарий, а не написал это ввиде ответа‍♀️

Это Ваш выбор. Так напишите! А мы все поучимся! Сколько раз ещё надо объяснять суть написанного? Я не знаю, какой код исполняется у автора и как. Вы указали, что может быть перегруз. Я согласился и ответил ВАМ, что ЛИЧНО Я использую такой цикл только в такой-то ситуации, зная, что использовать бесконечные циклы надо внимательно. В МОЁМ СЛУЧАЕ код не приводит к перегрузкам. Всё? Или ещё раз написать это? Мне больше нечего тут добавить!

@FoxFox  Свои примеры ответов на +- схожие вопросы я уже привел ранее в комментариях под самим вопросом. Так что не считаю необходимым повторно перепечатывать тут +- тот же код. А так как мы обсуждаем тут всё же ваш ответ, а не то как вы там у себя закулисами что используете, то еще раз повторюсь - ваш код в ответе создаёт проблему.

Это троллинг? Я уже всё объяснил!!! Меня Ваши комментарии НЕ ИНТЕРЕСУЮТ! Когда я сбрасывал ответ, никаких комментариев ещё не было. Не велика проблема была чтоб сразу не выдать ответ.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
